# What's the proper syntax for a SELECT INTO statement when using objective c with sqlite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, syntax

Right now my statement looks like this:

```
NSString *sqlJoin = @"SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM foods JOIN bridgeTable ON foods.foodID = bridgeTable.foodID";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlJoin UTF8String],
                      -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement); 
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Statement: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
NSLog(@"count: %i", [foodArray count]);
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
2012-07-06 10:32:04.940 ProFitness[7087:f803] Statement: near "INTO": syntax error
2012-07-06 10:32:04.940 ProFitness[7087:f803] count: 0
2012-07-06 10:32:04.940 ProFitness[7087:f803] sql statement: SELECT * FROM #tmp WHERE TableID = '3'
2012-07-06 10:32:04.941 ProFitness[7087:f803] Statement: near "#tmp": syntax error
```

If my syntax is wrong, what SHOULD it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the temporary temp yourself using:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE xxxx
```

then you would use

```
SELECT * INTO xxxx
```

For more information see [SQLite's Use Of Temporary Disk Files](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html).